# Get pid of FirefoxBinary object with python/selenium/firefox

Tags: python, selenium

I am using python/selenium/firefox to scrape different websites. The scrapers are running as .cgi scripts on my server. Now I need to to get the pid of the currently running webdriver.
Therefore I'm using this chunk of code

```
import psutil
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=pathToFF, firefox_binary=pathToBinaries, firefox_options=opts)
pid = driver.binary.process.pid
```

Unfortunately the following error occurs:

```
2018-05-31 08:05:59 'FirefoxBinary' object has no attribute 'process'
2018-05-31 08:05:59 line of error:557
```

So now my question is, how can I get the pid of my driver?

Answer (score 0):

If I try with:

```
driver.service.process.pid
```

it works.

The only thing is that, in my tests, I'm receiving the #`pid-1`. I mean, if 
 (for example) the test return `50654` actually the pid is:

```
davide.patti$ ps -ex | grep firefox
50655 ??         0:03.45 /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -marionette -profile /var/folders/b0/15xtry7n0157gq7m2j_n1srx2h0pkg/T/rust_mozprofile.rCHMaQdhIOyF
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is this ´-1´ a pattern, or does it depend on something, so it may be ´-2´ for some reason or what ever?

Comment: To be honest I don't know. In my tests is always the pid-1. Did you try?

Comment: That's obviously because driver.service.process.pid is not the browser's PID but the driver's PID. No, there's no guarantee, on my box it's -14 right now, perhaps because the driver process spawned 13 threads before it forked the browser process.
You can use OS process management APIs to list child processes of a parent.